# SQL Developer connection issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've installed jdk 1.6.0_45 and Oracle 11g. I  can correctly connect to The Oracle database using sqlplus with sqldba credentials, but when I am trying to connect to this database using SQL Developer I get an error "Listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor". I try to change "`SERVICE_NAME`" to "`SERVICE_NAME as SYSDBA`" and some other stuff but it does not help. How to make SQL developer connect to the server? Here is tnsname.ora file, img with connection setting and init.ora file and cmd prompt for connection from sqlplus

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Andriy\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME as SYSDBA = orcl.adobe.com)
    )
  )
```

[image]

```
# 
# $Header: rdbms/admin/init.ora /main/23 2009/05/15 13:35:38 ysarig Exp $ 
# 
# Copyright (c) 1991, 1997, 1998 by Oracle Corporation
# NAME
#   init.ora
# FUNCTION
# NOTES
# MODIFIED
#     ysarig     05/14/09  - Updating compatible to 11.2
#     ysarig     08/13/07  - Fixing the sample for 11g
#     atsukerm   08/06/98 -  fix for 8.1.
#     hpiao      06/05/97 -  fix for 803
#     glavash    05/12/97 -  add oracle_trace_enable comment
#     hpiao      04/22/97 -  remove ifile=, events=, etc.
#     alingelb   09/19/94 -  remove vms-specific stuff
#     dpawson    07/07/93 -  add more comments regarded archive start
#     maporter   10/29/92 -  Add vms_sga_use_gblpagfile=TRUE 
#     jloaiza    03/07/92 -  change ALPHA to BETA 
#     danderso   02/26/92 -  change db_block_cache_protect to _db_block_cache_p
#     ghallmar   02/03/92 -  db_directory -> db_domain 
#     maporter   01/12/92 -  merge changes from branch 1.8.308.1 
#     maporter   12/21/91 -  bug 76493: Add control_files parameter 
#     wbridge    12/03/91 -  use of %c in archive format is discouraged 
#     ghallmar   12/02/91 -  add global_names=true, db_directory=us.acme.com 
#     thayes     11/27/91 -  Change default for cache_clone 
#     jloaiza    08/13/91 -         merge changes from branch 1.7.100.1 
#     jloaiza    07/31/91 -         add debug stuff 
#     rlim       04/29/91 -         removal of char_is_varchar2 
#   Bridge     03/12/91 - log_allocation no longer exists
#   Wijaya     02/05/91 - remove obsolete parameters
#
##############################################################################
# Example INIT.ORA file
#
# This file is provided by Oracle Corporation to help you start by providing
# a starting point to customize your RDBMS installation for your site. 
# 
# NOTE: The values that are used in this file are only intended to be used
# as a starting point. You may want to adjust/tune those values to your
# specific hardware and needs. You may also consider using Database
# Configuration Assistant tool (DBCA) to create INIT file and to size your
# initial set of tablespaces based on the user input.
###############################################################################

# Change '<ORACLE_BASE>' to point to the oracle base (the one you specify at
# install time)

db_name='ORCL'
memory_target=1G
processes = 150
audit_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/admin/orcl/adump'
audit_trail ='db'
db_block_size=8192
db_domain=''
db_recovery_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/flash_recovery_area'
db_recovery_file_dest_size=2G
diagnostic_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>'
dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLXDB)'
open_cursors=300 
remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
# You may want to ensure that control files are created on separate physical
# devices
control_files = (ora_control1, ora_control2)
compatible ='11.2.0'
```

---

```
C:\>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ┬Є. ├Ёє 24 16:26:28 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

---

```
C:\>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 24-├╨╙-2013 17:00:25

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                24-├╨╙-2013 09:24:44
Uptime                    0 days 7 hr. 35 min. 43 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Andriy\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\app\andriy\diag\tnslsnr\andriypc\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: SQL Developer isn't using the `tnsnames.ora`, but neither is SQL*Plus from what you've shown. Are you sure your SID is `orcl`? What does `lsnrctl status` show?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for reply please check out the edition of question for `lsnrctl status` prompt

Comment: Can you do `alter system register;` from SQL*Plus, and then check `lsnrctl status` again to see if the SID is now listed? If not maybe check `show parameters listener` to see if local or remote is set, and check the alert and listener logs for errors.

Comment: @AlexPoole `alter system register` return 2. Is it correct prompt ?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes i can do `alter system register`. There is prompt `sytem altered`

Comment: But `show parameter listener` return empty values for `listener_network`, `local_listener` and `remote_listener`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43841/discussion-between-alex-poole-and-user2201747)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your listener is configured to only listen on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`). By default the database will attempt to register against the server's external host name ([the default when `local_listener` is blank](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams116.htm)), so registration seems to be failing.

The `listener.ora` can be modified to listen on the external address instead:

```
LISTENER = 
(DESCRIPTION_LIST = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)) 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ANDRIYPC)(PORT = 1521)) 
) 
)
```

... or the IP address rather than the host name if that isn't resolvable, e.g. `192.168.1.134`; but if you are using DHCP to get your IP address that will break when you're given a different IP. If you're using a static address then using that IP will be OK.

Alternatively, if you'll only ever access this DB from this PC and don't need it to be visible on the network, you can leave the listener on `localhost` and tell the DB to register there:

```
alter system set local_listener = '127.0.0.1:1521' scope=both;
alter system register;
```

Either way, `lsnrctl services` should now show `orcl.adobe.com`. When connecting from SQL Developer you can choose the 'Service name' radio button instead of SID, and put `orcl.adobe.com` in there as well.

If you're connecting as `SYS` you'll need to pick the `SYSDBA` role from the drop-down; but the first thing you should do really is create a new user for yourself and then only use that. Only use `SYS` (and `SYSTEM`, and other built-in accounts) for actual DBA tasks, not for creating your own tables etc.